# How to forward packets from PPP interface?

Tags: linux, routes

I hava one PPTP server(192.168.1.100/172.17.0.1), and need route all the packets(target ip is

172.17.0.11) from PPP virtual insterface to another server(10.10.1.2). so I can capture the packets

on 10.10.1.2, any suggestion? thanks!

BTW:172.17.0.1 is the vpn gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ip route add 172.17.0.11 via 10.10.1.2
Hope that help you.

Comment: could you tell the difference between "ip route add XXX" and "route add XXX", thanks!

Comment: it seems like route can not forward from ppp interface  :(